# where does QT go to look for fonts?

Tags: qt, fonts

I'm using QT-4 embedded-linux.

I have the following code in my QT application:

```
QFont newFont("wenquanyi", 8, QFont::Bold, true);

QApplication::setFont(newFont);
```

But the character cannot be displayed correctly. I do have a `wenquanyi_150_50.qpf` file under `QT-directory/lib/fonts` in my target linux device.

If I changed the code like this:

```
 QFont newFont("unifont", 8, QFont::Bold, true);
```

I can see the character being displayed correctly.

So i'm thinking that the problem is the about the path in which QT looks for a specific fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced issues like this when using Qt for Embedded Linux. Have a look at these:

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-deployment.html
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-fonts.html

and also try to use [QFontDatabase](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html). I found it very useful to get a list of all the fonts actually detected by QWS and of their features.

Comment: My  QFontDatabase  returns me back only 3 or 4 fonts, but I do have like 100 fonts in the lib/fonts directory. How does that come?