# How to locate and use fonts in Qt for Embedded Linux?

Tags: c++, css, qt, fonts, embedded-linux

This question might be related to this question:
[Where does QT go to look for fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276942/where-does-qt-go-to-look-for-fonts)

Im working with Ubuntu 14.04 and Qt for Embedded 4.8 and want to change the font of my application globally but I can only use a very small subset from my installed fonts.

The style of my application is loaded from a CSS file where I write:

```
QWidget {
   font-family: "DejaVu Sans"; /*or any other font*/
}
```

The problem is that Qt doesn't seem to be able to locate my installed fonts. According to the documentation [Deploying Qt for Embedded Linux Applications](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-deployment.html) Qt applications look for fonts in the *lib/fonts/* directory and specifically for the a file called *fontdir*. I don't know what this file is about and I cannot find it either. My full path for the fonts (for the debug build) is: */usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-x86-dbg/lib/fonts*

I use the QFontDatabase that can be found [in the Qt 4.8 docu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html#details) to print all my available fonts. Unfortunately the output is:

```
DejaVu Sans: Normal (11)
fixed: Normal (7 12)
helvetica: Normal (8 10 12 14 18 24) Italic (8 10 12 14 18 24) Bold (8 10 12 14 18 24) Bold Italic (8 10 12 14 18 24)
japanese: Normal (23)
micro: Normal (4)
unifont: Normal (16)
```

But I have way more fonts installed. The *DejaVu Sans*, for example exists in **bold** and other types too but only the "Normal" one is found. Here is only a small subset of fonts located in my fonts folder (those are located in the Qt folder for release and debug as well):

```
couri.pfa
cour.pfa
cursor.pfa
dejavu_sans_11_50.qpf2
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
DejaVuSansMono.ttf
DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
DejaVuSans.ttf
DejaVuSerif-BoldOblique.ttf
VeraMono.ttf
VeraSeBd.ttf
VeraSe.ttf
Vera.ttf
```

1. What is the *fontdir* file for, do I need it and how do I create it?
2. What do I have to do so that Qt finds all my installed fonts?
3. Is there a way to simply use a copy of my font of interest and put it into a sub-directory of my application to treat it like an icon so that I don't have to mess around with all the system locations?

**Edit:** According to this [thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52402-unable-to-find-font-when-placed-under-lib-font-dir) I think that I have also no support for TTF fonts. I had a look into my fonts and it appears that all *.qpf and *.qpf2 fonts are found. So I will try to convert my TTFs into QPFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the fontdir file for, do I need it and how do I create it?

This file is only required when QPF fonts should be used which is a Qt specific "light-weight" format. The Qt tool makeqpf uses the file (as far as I understood that).

> What do I have to do so that Qt finds all my installed fonts?

If Qt is compiled with *-no-freetype* then no TTF fonts can be used and are therefore not found by *QFontDatabase*. To enable the TTF support one has to compile Qt without this compile config flag. I have re-compiled it and all fonts inside */usr/local/Trolltech/QtEmbedded-4.8.6-x86-dbg/lib/fonts* were found.

> Is there a way to simply use a copy of my font of interest and put it
>   into a sub-directory of my application to treat it like an icon so
>   that I don't have to mess around with all the system locations?

Yes. One can simply use *QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont* which should not fail for supported font formats.

Note that I decided to re-compile Qt because I didn't want to mess with the makeqpf tool from Qt which could be used to convert TTF fonts to the QPF format.